# Update <TextInput /> value in react-admin with an API response?

Tags: react-admin, textinput

How can I change the `<TextInput />` value in react admin to get an updated value which is from the API response?

Here is the code:

```js
<TextInput source="..." label="..." />
```

I've tried to get used to `setValue`, and `getValues` from the `useForm` hook. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The react-admin@4.16.9 now using `react-hook-form`. So you can use the `useFormContext` to get the `setValue`

But it only effects when you wrap your form with the `FormProvider` (in react-admin the provider will be something like `<SimpleFormConfigurable>`)

```js
const ControlledTextInput = ({ value, ...props }) => {
  const { setValue } = useFormContext();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setValue(props.source, value);
  }, [value]);

  return <TextInput {...props} />;
};


// ==========

<SimpleFormConfigurable>
   <ControlledTextInput
      source="title"
      validate={required("Required field")}
      value="this value was provide by API response"
   />
</SimpleFormConfigurable>
```